# How do I seperate rows in list while using react-native-swipeout?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am using react-native-swipeout in order to implement a swiping functionality for each row in List & perform some actions. But the swiping get's applied to all row at once on swipe and not each row separately. Can anyone help me out how to separate the rows in a list and apply swipeout?

```
<Swipeout >
     <List
        dataSource=
        extraData={this.state.rowIndex}                      
          />
          )
</Swipeout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map` function

```js
        {this.state.contactData.map((rowdata, i) => {
                        return (<Swipeout>
                          <View key={i}>
                            <Text>{rowdata.listname}</Text>
                          </View>
                        </Swipeout>);
                    })}
```

Comment: Can you kindly share a sample or code snippet? I am new to react native and don't have much Idea. @hongdevelop

Comment: @AbhirupMukherjee You can use the code at the point where your Sweepout was located.

Comment: @AbhirupMukherjee Please show me the full code you are using.